# Laptop screen resolution stuck in 1280x800 - Ideapad Z580

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution, lcd, lenovo-laptop, intel-graphics

I had connected my laptop to an external LED display in the office on Windows 8.1. Before connecting the laptop, my display resolution was 1366x768 which was normal. Even while it was connected to the external display, the resolution was normal. I don't remember how I disconnected the display serial cable and put my computer to sleep that day. Maybe I just pulled the serial cable plug and closed the lid on my laptop. The next morning, I noticed that the display on my laptop was reduced to 1280x800 with refresh rate of 59Hz. I don't remember my refresh rate with 1366x768. There was no option to increase the resolution as there is no resolution beyond 1280x800. I have tried uninstalled the Intel graphics driver. Rebooting in safe mode and uninstalling the driver in that mode and restarting in normal and reinstalling the driver but none of it has helped. I upgraded yesterday to Windows 10 in the hope that my resolution problems will probably go away but nothing has helped.

At the moment, I have a 1 inch gap on the right portion of the screen. I have reduced the resolution further to 1280X768 because otherwise I cannot see the Windows taskbar as goes beyond the screen on the bottom. Reducing the resolution and center aligning the screen through my Intel Graphics Control Panel enables me to see 80% of the Windows taskbar at the bottom. At the top though, there is now a 0.5 inch gap because the screen has been center aligned. If you don't center align it, the screen sticks to the top but from the bottom, it cuts off.

On right portion of the screen, the gap doesn't go away. It stays black. Even in BIOS, the screen is like that. It's cut off from the right and extends beyond the screen limit on the bottom.

What do you think is wrong with it? Do I need to replace the LCD on the laptop or does it look like a software problem?

OS: Windows 10 and Windows 8.1
Laptop Model Lenovo Ideapad Z580
Inbuilt graphics card Intel HD 4000 - active
NVidia Geoforce disabled
Total Memory: 16GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I have two video cards in this laptop. I was currently running on Intel Graphics (UMA) only mode and had disabled the NVidia graphics card from the BIOS. While upgrading the BIOS as one of the solutions recommended by @Ulincsys, enabled the 'Optimus' option from the BIOS to see if that would make a difference. Viola and it did. I don't know what exactly is the science behind it. Whether my Intel graphics card is ruined but at least I have my native resolution back.

Comment: Congratulations! I am happy for you, please remember to mark your answer so others with this problem will be able to see the solution.

Answer (score 2):

If the graphics issue is showing up in bios, then it is not a problem with Windows. Have you tried changing display modes using keyboard shortcuts or BIOS settings? If neither of those work, I would try connecting your laptop to another display, and see if that doesn't fix the resolution problem.

Comment: I don't have any option to change the resolution in BIOS. The Lenovo BIOS seems to have very limited, basic functionality. It doesn't seem to be a Windows problem to me either because the initial boot screen from where you launch BIOS is also showing the same way with the right portion of the screen cut off. The Lenovo logo seems to have shifted to the left instead of being in the center.

Comment: Does it appear to be a screen problem? Should I get the screen replaced?

Comment: It could possibly be a screen problem, but at the moment, I am not 100% convinced that it is. Have you tried plugging your laptop into an external display yet, like I suggested above? Using the display from which the problem originated would be the best bet (the one in the office).

Comment: It didn't fix anything. Display on the led (same) was appearing correctly while my laptop screen still had the same problem.

Comment: Then it does sound like a screen problem.

Comment: I would be cautios in trying to get it fixed immidiately though. Try updating your bios first. Since the problem exists in your bios as well, it might be a problem there. If not, then you're probably looking at hardware.

Comment: After discussing this with you, I am inclining towards a screen problem. Will update the BIOS too if there is a new release but I doubt updating the BIOS will help. Will update this thread after updating BIOS.

Comment: I did update the BIOS but that didn't help.